# How to require deep nested NodeJS modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, node-modules

I have the following application structure:

```
application
|- config
|----- config.js
|- routes
|------ api
|-----------router.js 
|- Application.js
|- package.json
```

In /routes/api/router.js module I need to require /config/config.js file and do the following:

```
require('../../config/config.js');
```

I found the code above ugly and want to make it more pretty. Also if I move `/routes/api/router.js` to another folder I have to refactor all requires. What is the best practices to require that modules and is it possible to require config.js from application folder root, something like the following:

```
require('/config/config.js');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to get around this problem. One is to put all your shared code (like `config.js`) in a directory under `node_modules` (using `lib` here in case you want to have directories other than `config` in there):

```
application
|- node_modules
|----- lib
|---------- config
|-------------- config.js
|- routes
|------ api
|-----------router.js 
|- Application.js
|- package.json
```

So then you could require config.js using `require( 'lib/config/config.js' )`.

Alternatively, you could create a `lib` symlink in `node_modules` and link it to lib in your application directory structure:

```
application
|- node_modules
|----- lib -> ../../lib
|- lib
|------ config
|---------- config.js
|- routes
|------ api
|-----------router.js 
|- Application.js
|- package.json
```

One other alternative, which unfortunately is discouraged by the node docs, is to use [`NODE_PATH`](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders) which lets you specify directories that node's `require()` algorithm should look into. Following the same pattern as above with `lib`, you would do:

```
application
|- lib
|------ config
|---------- config.js
|- routes
|------ api
|-----------router.js 
|- Application.js
|- package.json
```

and set `NODE_PATH` equal to `$path_to_application/lib`.

**UPDATE**

Found [this great discussion](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520) on the topic which includes the options above as well as a few other ones.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I like the second approach that you've provided. Is it possible to create symlink in nodejs application itself instead to OS?

Comment: @Erik: Not sure exactly what you have in mind, but I just found [this great discussion](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520) of the options to solve this problem and updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use [path.resolve](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths). If you only give relative paths to `path.resolve` then it assumes they are relative to the current working directory, i.e. the project root. So all you need is:

```
const path = require('path');
path.resolve('config/config.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require('/config/config.js');
```

will not work as you are using the root of the system(os) not the root of the application.

```
var path=require('path');
var root=path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename);
```

or

```
var root=process.cwd();
```

will give you the root of the application. To navigate to config.js

```
path.resolve(root,'config/config.js)
```